# Using CGRect and CGContext to Create ImageView for Signature Box

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, cgcontext, cgrect

I create an image view for an app that I have the user use as a signature box. Right now I'm using the following code to create this "box".

```
imageFrame                = CGRectMake(self.view.center.x/2,
                            self.view.center.y/2,
                            self.view.frame.size.width/2,
                            self.view.frame.size.height/4);
```

I want to make that same rectangle using this code: basically a white box that has a signature box (an x and solid line for people to sign)

if I replace the code with this:

```
imageframe =
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();  
 CGContextConcatCTM(context, (CGAffineTransform){.a=1.0,.b=0.0,.c=0.0,.d=-1.0,.tx=0.0,.ty=480.0,});
// rect_canvas_background 
 CGContextMoveToPoint(context,-1.0f,-1.0f);
 CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,641.0f,-1.0f);
 CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,641.0f,481.0f);
 CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,-1.0f,481.0f);
 CGContextClosePath(context);
 CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
 CGContextEOFillPath(context);
```

I get multiple errors regarding all of the CGContext lines. I'm assuming I'm missing something simple with the way these things are done within iOS but I can't figure out what it is. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are the errors?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm concerned,

```
 CGContextConcatCTM(context, (CGAffineTransform){.a=1.0,.b=0.0,.c=0.0,.d=-1.0,.tx=0.0,.ty=480.0,});
```

contains variables preceding with '.'

Try by passing the values only. No variable assignment is required I guess.

If you get success, then let me know as well.